# Microsoft Bot Framework Composer integration with Bot Framework SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am looking to integrate a bot made with the Microsoft Framework Composer to one made in the SKD with C# dot net. Is there any documentation anywhere or anyone that knows how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it currently stands this answer is somewhat unclear. Could you include what kind of bots you're trying to integrate? Could you show us what you've tried and where you've looked for documentation?

Comment: I would also suggest that you remove the second paragraph because it isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks @KevinWells, I am trying to incorporate part of a bot build in Microsoft Bot Framework Composer with the Root Bot being built in Microsoft Bot Framework SDK 3.1 written in C# .NET
There isn't much more to tell. I am just wondering if anyone has any documentation or has successfully been able to complete this task?

It is hard to show where I looked, but here, Github, Microsoft, blogs, you name it...I was just hoping someone in this community might have done it and could have pointed me in the right directions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that's "not doable" (in a "reasonable" amount of time).

The point is that SDK 3, lacks support for [Adaptive Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), which are **THE** cornerstone of Composer.

Also, Adaptive Dialogs have a large set of new features, like [Adaptive Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Language Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-language-generation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Interruption handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-dialog-interruptions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and so many others, that have no equivalent in SDK v3, that you could end with a nice bot design in Composer that wouldn't "run" in SDK v3.

Not to mention that you [can't deploy new v3 bots anymore](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/06/07/v3-bot-broadcast-message/).

Even though Adaptive Dialogs have a steep learning curve, specially coming from v3, it's worth taking your time to learn them, because they can make you work much more faster than v3.

So, take the plunge

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is great to know. I am enjoying the use of adaptive dialog in composer. Is there a way to do it with SDK4? We will need to remake our root bot soon anyway...

Comment: Yes you can, I've been working with adaptive dialogs in SDK4 for a little while and I like them a lot, because there's very little boilerplate.

Comment: I'm actually going to give Composer a try now, I had rejected it in the beginning but I realized it was b/c I didn't understand adaptive dialogs. BTW, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into the opposite problem, i.e. I would like to use the full SDK features in a Composer-generated bot.

However during my search I encountered various hints that might just help with what you are trying to achieve:

- [Adding Bot Framework Composer dialogs to a Skill](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/experimental-add-composer/): still marked as experimental, but seems that you can have a root bot and integrate a Composer bot while still being able to continue working with Composer. Looks promising to me.
- Another option I see is to consume the Composer-bot as a skill in the SDK-bot as the root. However I have not seen any documentation thereof (only the other way round).